# How to rollback a table in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

One table has been truncated by mistake and inserted few records in the table. So could you please suggest how to get the previous table back

Comment: Do you have a backup? Otherwise you're a little bit screwed... You will have to restore and then manually figure out which records were added.

Comment: Get the latest copy of your backup, restore to a **different** database, and copy the data back across. If you're using tranasction backups, you'll be able to do a point in time restore to the moment before you `TRUNCATE` (may take a few attempts to find the exact moment). If you're using Simple then any changes since the backup **will be lost**. Then learn from your mistakes and don't run `TRUNCATE` against production tables.

Comment: ROLLBACK is something that happens to open transactions. Once you have committed the transaction there is no ROLLBACK.

Comment: check for sql logs, you can retrieve the state by re-running the logs

Comment: @Manish This is what point in time recovery does. If you meant something different as this is not possible then, not straightforwardly, you would need a third party tool that understands the SQL Server transaction log format and to hope that the operation is still contained in the transaction log and hasnt been overwritten

Answer (score 0):

**RESTORE YOUR BACKUP**

One of the advantages of a truncate is it almost doesn't let a footprint in the log. A delete affects row-by-row while the truncate is a lot faster because it completely deallocates the data pages, at once.
After the commit, there's nothing left to be rolled back.

**EDIT**

If there any identity in that table it will also be reset. So any inserts will "duplicate" truncated ids.

Comment: The OP will love to hear that trunc is an "advantage" ^^

Comment: @SQLPolice Sure, that ill justify why they used it instead of an ordinary delete without where

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "Without a log, without a rollback."? If you were trying to say it isnt possible to rollback TRUNCATE as it isnt logged this isnt true. The page deallocations can be rolled back. But the issue is that nothing can be rolled back once the transaction is comitted.

Comment: @MartinSmith Yeah, I mean after the commit.